# SQL Sum for every day

Tags: sql-server, sum

I have lots of data in my `count` field with different dates.
How can I make a query that groups by date and sum of count for every date ?

My sample data is below :

```
  count    date
   2       2018-07-03 19:06:24.501
   5       2018-07-03 02:06:24.112
   3       2018-07-04 17:06:24.426
   2       2018-07-04 14:06:24.241
   5       2018-07-05 19:06:24.431
   2       2018-07-05 11:06:24.521
   5       2018-07-06 22:06:24.103
   4       2018-07-06 08:06:24.530
```

Now I want my result data :

```
 sum count    date
   7        2018-07-03 
   5        2018-07-04 
   7        2018-07-05 
   9        2018-07-06
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cast your Date column to Date only and get rid of the time part of the datetime values, also group by that Date and it should give you what you want. Something like this...

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)                AS [Sum Count]
      , CAST([Date] AS DATE)    AS [Date]
FROM TableName
GROUP BY CAST([Date] AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ANSI SQL `cast()` function with `GROUP BY` Clause  :

```
select sum(cnt), cast(dt as date)
from table t
group by cast(dt as date);
```

Answer (score 1):

CAST your datetime to date

```
SELECT SUM(a.count),CAST(a.date as date)
FROM <table> a
GROUP BY CAST(a.date as date)
```